# OM: deref cursors in event handlers?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I'm trying to understand when we must deref a cursor to get its value.

In the [om cursors wiki](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Cursors) it states that 
event handlers are considered not part of the render phase, and therefore cursors in handlers should be drefed.
Same is shown in the [Basic-tutorial](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial):

```
(defn contact-view [contact owner]
  (reify
    om/IRenderState
    (render-state [this {:keys [delete]}]
      (dom/li nil
        (dom/span nil (display-name contact))
        (dom/button #js {:onClick (fn [e] (put! delete @contact))} "Delete")))))
```

But, in the [TodoMVC code](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/item.cljs),  the handlers (onclick, onchange...) use the cursor without derefing it:

```
(dom/button
   #js {:className "destroy"
        :onClick (fn [_] (put! comm [:destroy todo]))}))
```

So, what is the correct way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `delete` and `comm` are not cursors but core.async channels. The `put!` operation adds a message to the channel which is handled [here](https://github.com/swannodette/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/om/src/todomvc/app.cljs#L118).

Cursors are a way of wrapping state (called app-state in om). There are two things you might want to do with that state:

1. Change the state: when you want to change your app-state, you call `om/transact!` or `om/update!` on one the cursors to the app-state (deref never needed). Om schedules this transaction to be shown in the next render phase.
2. Read the state: when reading during the render phase (inside the `render` and `render-state` functions, the cursor works like its value, i.e., you don't need to deref it. At any other point in time, the cursor might be being transacted on or have a schedule transaction, so you want to deref it to get the current value and not some inconsistent state.